# Why my model does not trigger some events after created or updated

Tags: laravel

I would like to trigger some actions after either a save or an update on a model.

```
I wrote this in my model :

public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        
        self::created(function($appAnswer){
            Log::info('created');
        });
        
        self::updated(function($appAnswer){
            Log::info('updated');
        });
        
        Log::info('toto');

       
    }
```

When I create or update this model, I have only that in the log file:

```
[2018-07-06 11:06:15] local.INFO: toto  
[2018-07-06 11:11:34] local.INFO: toto  
[2018-07-06 11:19:54] local.INFO: toto  
[2018-07-06 11:20:20] local.INFO: toto  
[2018-07-06 11:20:32] local.INFO: toto
```

It means that the created and updated "events" are never triggered.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: You follow https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events link.

Answer (score 0):

I understood my problem. It is in the doc :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#updates

> When issuing a mass update via Eloquent, the saved and updated model events will not be fired for the updated models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a mass update.

I made a change and it works now.